# TouchableOpacity не срабатывает

Tags: react-native

Я тестирую приложение не на эмуляторе, а на подключенном телефоне (Android). Не понимаю, почему при нажатии на кнопку анимация происходит, но сам факт нажатия обрабатывается не с 1 раза, не переключает на следующий экран
activeOpacity пытался менять, не имеет значения

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, SafeAreaView, ImageBackground, Image, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { gStyle } from "../Styles/Styles";


export default function Main({ navigation }){

    const loadset = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Settings')
        console.log('presssssssssssed')
    }
    const image = require('../images/image104.png');
    const imagebar = require('../images/Rectangle3.png');
    const homeimb = require("../images/Ellipse1.png");
    const homeim = require("../images/Vector.png");
    const list = require("../images/listscreen.png");
    const prof = require("../images/profile.png")
    return(
    <SafeAreaView style={gStyle.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={image} resizeMode="cover" style={gStyle.image}>
            <Text style = {gStyle.hellotex}>Добрый день, USERNAME</Text>
            <View style={gStyle.viewst3} />
                <Image style = {gStyle.homeb} source={homeimb}/>
                <Image style = {gStyle.homeim} source={homeim}/>
                <Image style={gStyle.bar} source={imagebar}/>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={(loadset)} activeOpacity = {0.02}>
            <Image source={list} style = {gStyle.listpos}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
            <Image source={prof} style = {gStyle.profpos}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в стиле картинки, использующейся как кнопка, было
position: "absolute",
нужно поменять "absolute" на "relative"